# Closed form of $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+1}, a_1=1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I would like to find the general term, closed form or analytic solution for the recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+1},a_1=1$.

I looked around the internet but could not find much about this problem. If anyone knows any paper or research about this problem, I would like to know.

**My research:**

- [The sequence is a bounded increasing sequence and converges to $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq?noredirect=1&lq=1).
- [The sequence is contractive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724511/how-do-you-show-%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D-%5Csqrt%7Ba_n-%2B1%7D%24-is-contractive%3F).
- [A similar problem $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+2}, a_1=\sqrt{2}$ has a closed form $a_n=2\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304500/recurrence-relations-solving-for-%24b_n%24).
- [A similar problem $a_{n+1}=a_{n}^2+c$ does not(?) have a simple solution except for $c=0,-2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34938/when-does-iterating-z-mapsto-z2-c-have-an-exact-solution?rq=1) (I am not sure if I understand what's written here)

The 3rd website and 4th website seems to be related since the equation $a_{n+1}=a_{n}^2+c$ turns into $a_n=\sqrt{a_{n+1}-c}$ and if we swap $a_n,a_{n+1}$ and set $c=-2$(which is one of the values mentioned) we get $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+2}$. However, I do not know how to make use of this connection.

Comment: I think the relation with the 4th website is that if we set $b_n=a_n^2$ then $b_{n+1} = \sqrt{b_n-c}$ (that seems more precise than swapping $a_n,a_{n+1}$).

Comment: Have you tried to put $ a_n=\cosh(\theta_n)$

Comment: @GregMartin Does that really work? Assuming $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+c$, I got $b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}^2=(a_n^2+c)^2=(b_n+c)^2$ which looks different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but it is close.

Define the constants
$$ s:=\sqrt{5},\; g:=(1+s)/2,\text{ and }
c\approx -2.1972839287883129714.$$
Define using power series the function

$$ T(x) := x + \frac{5 - s}{20} x^2 + \frac{5 s - 11}{20} x^3 +
 \frac{497 s - 1110}{3800} x^4 + \cdots. $$

Define the sequences

$$ b_n := T(c\cdot(2g)^{-n}), \qquad a_n := g+b_n. $$

Note that $\,\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = 0\,$ and
$\,\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = g.\,$
The sequence $\,a_n\,$ satisfies

$$ a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+1},\qquad a_1=1. $$

Unfortunately, I can only determine the coefficients of $\,T(x)\,$
one by one and have no closed form for the function itself
or its coefficients.

---

Some more details are here. The idea is to ensure that

$$ g \!+\! T(x) \!=\! \sqrt{g^2 \!+\! T(2gx)},\;
\text{ or }\;T(x)^2\!=\! T(2gx) \!-\! 2gT(x). $$

Given the definition of $\,a_n\,$ this implies that
$\,a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n+1}.\,$

Use the method of undetermined coefficients, to solve for
the coefficients of $\,T(x)\,$ one by one. For example,
assume that $\, T(x) = x + u_2x^2 + O(x^3).\,$ Then use
$\, x^2 + O(x^3) = (2gx + u_2(2gx)^2) - (2gx + 2gu_2x^2) =  (5+s)u_2x^2\,$ to solve for $\,u_2.$

The value of $\,c\,$ is determined as the unique value that
yields $\,a_1 = 1.\,$ Also, it is the limit
$\,c = \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n(2g)^n.\,$

Comment: I have three questions. (1) I am not sure how to prove that $a_n$ satisfies the equation. Could you elaborate? (2) I know you said you don’t have closed form for the coefficients of T, but can you describe the algorithm to derive them? (3) How did you get $c$?

Comment: @Kaira Thanks for that helpful comment! I will add more details.